# Magento 2 not install in my local server

Tags: magento-2.1, installation

I am trying to install magento 2 on local server. 
But I am getting this error.

[image]

I have changes in php.ini file in local server. But this error didn't fix.
I have remove comment xsl and intl extension and restart server but not working.
Please suggest me how to fix this issue.
I am new on magento 2.

Here is php info :

[image]

Comment: Can you check in your phpinfo, that the php ini is correct which is updated? I mean the path of the php ini.

Comment: I have to ini file. First is *php.ini-development* and second is *php.ini-production* . I am changes both file but not wotking

Comment: what is the path in phpinfo?

Comment: path is : xampp/php/php.ini-development or php.ini-production
there is two file.

Comment: What is the Loaded Configuration File in your phpinfo?

Comment: can you share screenshot of you info?

Comment: Please check my edited question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73069/discussion-between-rakesh-patidar-and-dev-67commerce).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not need to set permission means may be you are install in windows xampp or wampp,

First open php.ini file and uncomment following line

```
;extension=php_xsl.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

After restart your apache server

And may be need to change your php version, review bellow ticket for addtional information

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4344

Comment: I have complete this process but not success.

Comment: check your apache version.

Comment: Appache version is Apache/2.4.17

Comment: have you restart your apache ?

Comment: restart apache server and share your installation error scrrenshot

Comment: Yes, I have restart apache server and my pc. But getting same error.

Comment: check in php info and make sure following extension will be displayed or not?|

php_xsl and php_intl.dll

Comment: php_xsl are showing but php_intl.dll not showing